# Using google-diff-match-patch in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-diff-match-patch

I'd like to use the `google diff/match/patch lib` in an angular app to show the difference between two texts.

My usage would be something like this:

```
public ContentHtml: SafeHtml;
compare(text1: string, text2: string):void {
        var dmp = new diff_match_patch();

        dmp.Diff_Timeout = 1;
        dmp.Diff_EditCost = 4;

        var d = dmp.diff_main(text1, text2);
        dmp.diff_cleanupSemantic(d);
        var ds = dmp.diff_prettyHtml(d);

        this.ContentHtml = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(ds);
}
```

Problem is, how do I import `diff_match_patch` for this line?
`var dmp = new diff_match_patch();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the npm package for angular project in `package.json`.

```
"diff-match-patch": "^1.0.5",
```

and import in component as:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import DiffMatchPatch from 'diff-match-patch';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  getDiff() {
    var dmp = new DiffMatchPatch();
    var diff = dmp.diff_main('Hello', 'Hallo');
    // Result: [(-1, "Hell"), (1, "G"), (0, "o"), (1, "odbye"), (0, " World.")]
    dmp.diff_cleanupSemantic(diff);
    // Result: [(-1, "Hello"), (1, "Goodbye"), (0, " World.")]
    console.log(diff);
  }

}
```

[Here is a demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/diff-match-patch-playground-2ey6rw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Do I need to add the package to webpack or something, too? After adding this I got an error on loading `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)` and I'm not sure why

Comment: @Sam : I tried using the same code on a small demo project of angular and things worked fine when I served using `ng serve` and also tried `ng build --prod` . Are you getting the error when you are running `ng s` ?  For the provided error, there are few solutions I found : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549923/angular2-cannot-read-property-call-of-undefined-when-bootstrapping . Do let me know more about your implementation.

Comment: @Sam: any luck ?

Comment: In the end it was as simple as cleaning up the cache :/
Sorry it took me so long...

Comment: @Sam : Glad to hear that it got fixed. Cheers !

Answer (score 3):

Building on top of @Shashank's answer -- to ensure type safety, you can also install the [corresponding type defs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/diff-match-patch) via:

```sh
npm i -D @types/diff-match-patch
or 
yarn add -D @types/diff-match-patch
```

These type defs haven't changed much since 2017 which means you won't be able to use

```js
import DiffMatchPatch from 'diff-match-patch';
```

because the types have no default export — they only export the rather poorly named `diff_match_patch` *class* (which looks like a *function*) -- which you were trying to run in the first place!

However, typescript also supports [import renaming](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-single-export-from-a-module) with which you can import the instantiable class we're all used to:

```js
import { diff_match_patch as DiffMatchPatch } from 'diff-match-patch';
```

Once imported properly, you'll be able to enjoy intellisense and more:

[image]

Comment: You'll probably also need to add `diff-match-patch` to your `angular.json` config now to avoid the commonJS warning: `"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [ "diff-match-patch" ]`